# Conversion from ‘callback<void>::func*’ to non-scalar type ‘callback<void>’ requested error when using g++ 4.8.3?

Tags: c++, stl

For understanding c++'s template and function object, I want to create a template class callback which is a type that approximates function currying.  The object of type `callback<R, B1>` contains a member `R operator() (B1)`, Thus callbacks are function objects with the first template type specifying the return of the function and the remaining arguments specifying the types of the arguments to pass the function. This method was used by [SFS](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/06wi-cs240d/src/sfs-0.8pre.tar.gz). But when I used the following code to create an instance and compiled it, I got a error:

```
template<typename R, typename F1 = void> class callback;
template<typename R>
class callback<R>{
  public:
    struct func {
        virtual R operator()() = 0;  
    };   
    typedef struct func *fptr;

public:
    template<typename B1>  struct pfunc_0_1 : public func{
        typedef R(*fp_t)(B1); 
        fp_t fp;
        B1 b1;
        pfunc_0_1(fp_t fp, const B1& b1) : fp(fp), b1(b1) {
            cout << "4444\n";
        }
        R operator() () {
            return fp(b1);
        }
    };

  template<typename B1, typename B1x>
  static func* init( R(*fp)(B1), const B1x& b1){
    return new pfunc_0_1<B1>(fp, b1);
  }

};//class callback
```

I got the error when compiling:

```
forstack.cc:26:65: error: conversion from ‘callback<void>::func*’ 
                  to non-scalar type    callback<void>’ requested
 callback<void> cb0 = callback<void>::init(printmsg, "Dillon\n");
```

what knowledge I need for this problem? thanks!

EDIT: According to answers from @denis-bu and @TheOne, I can add two statements:

```
typedef struct func *fptr;
private:
   mutable fptr fn;
public:  
   callback(fptr fn) : fn(fn) {std::cout << "1111\n";}
```

but I don't know such c++'s mechanism or what rule c++ used to find or know to call this constructor function:

```
 callback(fptr fn) : fn(fn) {std::cout << "1111\n";}
```

Comment: My guess is that you try to initialize `callback<void>` with `callback<void>::init(...)`, which returns `callback<void>::func*` and there is no conversion from `::func*` to `callback<T>`

Comment: The error is obvious. What you actually *want* is not. What do you want that line to do?

Comment: agreing with nvoigt, do you want to store/keep a pointer to the new callback object? have you only used the wrong type? ( callback<void> cb0 instead of callback<void>::func* cb0 )

Comment: @abelard20008, rule you are talking about is standard c++ converisions. You can tak a look at this article(see "Implicit conversions with classes"): http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a brain teaser.

My guess is that `callback<void>` doesn't have constructor which accepts `callback<void>::func*`.

So, you should either change `cb0`'s type to `callback<void>::func*` or add constructor to `callback` which accepts `callback<R>::func*`. This depends on what you're intended to do... :)

Comment: I agree to the first part. As the callback<R> class has no data member having a proper constructor doesn't help too much.

Comment: @StefanoBuora, I need a pointer to the new callback object, so in my own answer, I add a constructor function.but I can not understand what rule c++ obeys to call my added function, please help me!

Comment: I believe, at the end, that you want just to build a functor. Please read some articles looking for "C++ functor". My guess is that at the end you will find that your code is more complicate than the real needed. Probably you will find also that your init function will be the constructor of your functor and the functor itself wil be a mix of the struct func and the internals template.

Comment: @StefanoBuora, You are right, the final code must be very complicate. Now I want to understand the details through this little example, then I will use perl to auto producing code like this (this method was used by [SFS](http://www.pdos.lcs.mit.edu/papers/sfs:sigops-euro8.ps.gz)). Of course I should learn more "c++ functor" as you said

Answer (score 0):

According to answers from @denis-bu and @TheOne, I can add two statements:

```
  typedef struct func *fptr;
  private:
     mutable fptr fn;
  public:  
     callback(fptr fn) : fn(fn) {std::cout << "1111\n";}
```

but I don't know such c++'s mechanism or what rule c++ used to find or know to call this constructor function:

```
 callback(fptr fn) : fn(fn) {std::cout << "1111\n";}
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing that you edit into the question, not post as an answer.

Comment: @Yann4,It seems that you did not compare the code to the original, thanks for your attention!